# mirror login with php and jquery

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have websiteA and websiteB. websiteB is coded in PHP+MYSQL.
Both websites use jquery.

Everything works like this: the user logs in on websiteA and after this happens I want to log him automatically to websiteB, so that if he goes to websiteB in a new tab, he is already logged in there and will not have to manually login.

I have access to both websites, but they are located on different servers.

Right now, once the user logs in on websiteA, I am sending a request to websiteB using jquery post, containing the encrypted username+password.
The login form works fine on websiteB, but there seems to be a problem with the sessions. The user is not logged in on websiteB even if the data was sent correctly and the login form works fine.

So I tried to do this:

1.user logs in on websiteA.

2.send request to websiteB and retrieve the session_id, using jquery post. We'll call the session id "sess1";

3.then I sent the username+password+session_id(sess1) to websiteB

Now websiteB has the session data and when I try to do the login on websiteB, I also try to set a custom session_id, based on the data previously retrieved.
So I use this code on websiteB:

```
<?php 
session_id($_POST['session_id']);
session_start();
?>
```

If I keep sending POST requests to retrieve the session_id from websiteA to websiteB, the session_id is the original one(sess1), which is correct. Now if I open websiteB in a new browser page, the session_id is different. Like if I ran two different sessions on same browser.

This is probably because websiteB considers the data incoming from websiteB as being a client, and then when I open websiteB it treats it as another client.

So the question is, how can I mirror a login usign jquery or curl?

The only way right now seems to be to open a popup window containing the login data for websiteB as parameters.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [OAuth implementation](https://www.google.nl/search?q=php+oauth+implementation&oq=php+oauth+impleme&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3j69i64.2740j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). I'd advise you to do some research on the topic first, because it is quite a broad topic ;) With specifics you're more then welcome to ask help!

Comment: I agree with @giorgio, OAuth it's a little bit complicated but effective and secure. I had the same problem as you but the different webpages were on the same server so it's was more easy for me.

Comment: What if websiteA is using JSP and websiteB is using PHP ... can OAuth still be used? 

Thanks for the suggestion, btw. I will start reading about it. I eventually came with a more custom solution based on my requirement which requires some improvisations, but your suggestion will be helpful for future development. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, that's the beauty of OAuth. You send/receive the data as a JSON object, as a normal GET request with query parameters, as an XML call, basically any common data-format. For further reading, start [here](http://oauth.net/) and Google some, but also read the [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq) and the [Github](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) FAQ, they both use oAuth and have a pretty good explanation of what happens in an OAuth request, although implementations are slightly different.

Comment: Oh and ofcourse, [SO is a nice reference as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oauth) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that both websites share access to the same database.

If so, I would suggest adding a column to the users table that will be used as a single-use login key. Also, another column for expiration time of that key (unless you keep track of last-login times).

1. User Logs into ws1
2. ws1 validates credentials
3. if credentials are valid generate random key and update appropriate table columns (tempkey value and expiration)
4. Page is rendered with javascript/jquery set to send a request to ws2([http://ws2.com/login.jsp?tempkey=[...]](http://ws2.com/login.jsp?tempkey=%5b...%5d))
5. ws2's login.jsp sees the tempkey and initiates a secondary login method
6. Secondary login on ws2 searches for the key in the users table and begins a new session for the user, bypassing normal login procedures.
7. ws2 sends the cookie for the session on ws2 back to the user through the jquery connection on ws1's page

In this case, there would be a different session_id for each site. I don't know if you're trying to share session data beyond just the user's identity. That would require some more technical knowledge to give a more thorough answer but the premise would be similar.

Hope that helps,
fie